Jacobi's formula via Determinant of Matrix Exponential, Equivalence of Equations?
Be $A$ a invertible and differentiable linear map.
Jacobi's formula states that $\frac{d}{dt}\det{A} = det A \cdot tr(A^{-1}\cdot \frac{d\,A}{dt})$.
It is a often derived corollary that  $\det e^{B} = e^{tr B}$.
However I want to know if/show that these equations are equivalent.
The corollary can be also derived for diagonalizable matrices and then generalized due the density of diagonalizable linear maps in the space of all linear maps.
Now I will use this altnernative proof to find the stated corollary:
$\frac{d}{dt} \det A = \frac{d}{dt} \det e^B = \frac{d}{dt}(e^{tr B}) = (tr B)'e^{tr B} = (tr B)' \det A$
Here I use that every invertible matrix $A$ can be expressed by exponentiation of at least one matrix $B$.
As the trace is linear, it commutes with the derivative.
$(tr B)' = tr B' = tr (logA)' = tr A^{-1 } \frac{dA}{dt}$
This gives us again Jacobi's formula.
Do I have shown the equivalence of Jacobi's formula and the Determinant of Matrix Exponential formula?
Jacobi's formula has a more general form with the adjugate, the given formula only holds for invertible $A$.
How may I generalize my result?
By using $A^{-1} = \frac{1}{det A} adj(A)$ I of course get the general form, but by using a proof that relies on invertibilty, it seems like I lost the generality?
Can I again make a density argument with invertible matrices?
I apologize for using matrices and linear map interchangeable.
I relied on $(log A)' = A^{-1} A'$ and $(e^A)' = e^A A'$.
Is $e^A A' = A' e^A$?
Why do they commute?
Is the following correct?
This relies on $[A,A']=0$, doesn't it?
For diagonal matrices this is clear and it should follow for all matrices! Any objections why it shouldn't follow from similarity to diagonal matrices with constant basis changes and then again density of diagonal maps?
I hope someone can verify or disprove the equivalence and provide some insight on my closing questions!
Thank you

It is not the case that $de^A=A' e^A dt$; I understand that in your example the elements of matrix $A$ are all functions of $t$. However the differential of $e^A$ w.r.t. $A$ does not result in a form like ${\sf d}e^A=e^A {\sf d}A$;  only ${\rm tr} ({\sf d} e^A) = {\rm tr} (e^A {\sf d}A)$.

Do you have any references for this? And an example why my formulation doesn't work?

By the way, the main problem with your approach is that you are trying to prove a theorem from its corollary.

Again, not what I'm trying to do. I know two theorems from different sources. One is presented as a corollary on Wikipedia. So I was wondering as "The corollary can be also derived for diagonalizable matrices" via the argument you also shown, if these are equivalent - meaning, I want to proof that these are equivalent theorems by assuming the Corollary is shown via the argument already discussed, and starting from this, that I can show Jacobi's formula from $det e^A = e^{tr A}$. Maybe I misrepresented my attempt in the question above. But I thank you for your time and advice. It was helpful.

$\def\det{\operatorname{det}}$
$\def\tr{\operatorname{tr}}$
$\def\df{{\sf d}}$
$\def\qty#1{\left( #1 \right)}$
Given a matrix $B$,
$$
\df e^B = \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{1}{(k+1)!}\sum_{j=0}^{k}B^j \df B B^{k-j}
$$
(see Matrix Algebra, Chapter 13, Karim M. Abadir and Jan R. Magnus, Cambridge University Press, 2005). Using the formula for the determinant we have,
$$
\df \det e^B = \det e^B \tr \qty{ e^{-B} \df e^B}
$$
since the inverse of $e^B$ is $e^{-B}$. We can write,
$$
\tr \qty{ e^{-B} \df e^B}
=
\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{1}{(k+1)!}\sum_{j=0}^{k} \tr \qty{e^{-B}B^j (\df B) B^{k-j}}
$$
Using the property of the trace of a product of matrices,
$$
\tr \qty{e^{-B}B^j (\df B) B^{k-j}}
=
\tr \qty{e^{-B} B^{k-j}B^j \df B }
=
\tr \qty{e^{-B} B^{k} \df B }
$$
we have,
$$
\tr \qty{ e^{-B} \df e^B}
=
\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{1}{(k+1)!}\sum_{j=0}^{k} \tr \qty{e^{-B}B^{k} \df B }
=
\tr \qty{
e^{-B}
\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{1}{k!} B^{k} \df B
}
=
\tr \qty{
e^{-B}
e^B \df B
}
=\tr \df B
$$
Consolidate these into,
$$
\df \det e^B = \det e^B \tr \df B
$$
and note that $\tr \df B = \df \tr B$. Since $y=\det e^B$ and $x=\tr B$ are scalars we have,
$$
dy = y dx \implies y =c e^x
$$
If $O$ is the additive identity matrix $B+O=B$ we have,
$$
\det e^O = c e^{\tr O} = c
$$
and since $e^O=I$, $c=1$. Therefore $\det e^B = e^{\tr B}$.

To see why $\df e^X \neq e^X \df X$ lets look at the definition of $e^X$:
$$
e^X := I + X + \frac{1}{2!} X^2 + \ldots = \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{1}{k!} X^k 
$$
where $X^0=I$. Now for any product $X^k$, $k \in \mathbb N$ we have,
$$
\df X^k = \underbrace{(\df X) X^{k-1} + X (\df X) X^{k-2} + \ldots + X^{k-2}(\df X) X+  X^{k-1} (\df X)}_{\text{$k$ terms}}
$$
which can be written as,
$$
\df X^k = \sum_{j=0}^{k-1} X^j (\df X) X^{k-j-1}
$$
and so we have,
$$
\df e^X = \sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{1}{k!} \sum_{j=0}^{k-1} X^j (\df X) X^{k-j-1}
$$
since $\df X^0 =\df I = O \df X$. Use $k'=k-1$ to get,
\begin{align}
\df e^X & = \sum_{k'=0}^\infty \frac{1}{(k'+1)!} \sum_{j=0}^{k'} X^j (\df X) X^{k'-j} \\
& = \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{1}{(k+1)!} \sum_{j=0}^{k} X^j (\df X) X^{k-j} & \text{rename $k'$ to $k$}
\end{align}
If $X^j (\df X) X^{k-j}$ could be written as $X^j X^{k-j}(\df X) $ then we would end up with $\df e^X = e^X \df X$. But $(\df X) X^{k-j} \neq X^{k-j} \df X$.

For any square matrix $B$ we can write,
$$
B = M D M^{-1}
$$
where $D$ is a diagonal matrix of the eigenvalues of $B$ and $M$ is the matrix of the eigenvectors of $B$. Then for any power of $B$
$$
B^k = M D^k M^{-1}
$$
and so,
$$
e^B = \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{1}{k!}B^k 
= \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{1}{k!}M D^k M^{-1}
= M \qty{\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{1}{k!} D^k} M^{-1}
= M e^D M^{-1}
$$
Therefore,
$$
\det e^B = \det \qty{ M e^D M^{-1}} = \det e^D
$$
Since,
$$
D^k =
\begin{bmatrix}
\lambda_1^k & \\
 & \lambda_2^k & &\\
 & & \ddots & \\
 & & & \lambda_n^k
\end{bmatrix}
$$
it follows that,
$$
e^D =
\begin{bmatrix}
e^{\lambda_1} & \\
 & e^{\lambda_2} & &\\
 & & \ddots & \\
 & & & e^{\lambda_n}
\end{bmatrix}
$$
So we have,
$$
\det e^D = \prod_{i=1}^n e^{\lambda_i}= e^{\sum_{i=1}^n \lambda_i}
$$
Since for any $n \times n$ matrix,
$$
\tr B = \sum_{i=1}^n \lambda_i
$$
we conclude that,
$$
\det e^B = e^{\tr B}
$$

I will look into your reference. Thanks for the answer. But most of my questions remain: Are both formulas equivalent? Can I use a density argument? Do A and A' commute? And I didn't really use the derivative of e^X but just e^trX (I'm sorry I overlooked it), didn't I?

What I have done is to show how to go from Jacobi's formula to the corollary. I will try to write 'a density argument'. $A$ and ${\sf d}A$ do not commute (to convince yourself write $A{\sf d}A$ and $({\sf d}A) A$ for a $2 \times 2$ matrix. Your proof seems circular to me; you try to prove the corollary by substituting the formula of the corollary in Jacobi's formula.

No, please don't misunderstand me. I want to show that the corollary is equivalent to Jacobi's formula. A proof of the corollary (like you have given no) based on diagonalization and trace as sum and det as product of eigenvalues is well known to me from two different courses. I now want to show that Jacobi's formula can be derived from this knowledge. The wikipedia article for Jacobi's formulat presents different proofs for the formula, one of it is also based on diagonalization arguments. This lead me to believing both theorems are equivalent. I wanted feedback if this equivalence holds.

This was the main reason for my post. And when writing I came across the other questions. Do you understand what I was trying to do?

@theta_phi then all you need to prove is that ${\sf d}{\rm tr}, B = {\rm tr}(e^{-B} {\sf d}e^B)$, how hard can that be?

Thanks, I will give it a try. I believe I understand your comments better now.
